# barChart starts from Middle of Screen instead of Top , why?

Tags: java, bar-chart, codenameone

When I have set height of barChart to  screenHeight then the chart starts from middel of screen ,it should start from top of Screen and its screenshot is attached[image]

```
Tabs chartTabs = new Tabs();
  chartTabs.setPreferredH(screenHeight);
chartTabs.addTab("", icon1, new BarChartGenerator().getBarChart(dealersNames, dealersValues));


public Component getBarChart(ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> nameList, ArrayList<ArrayList<Double>> valueList) {
        String[] titles = new String[]{"2017"};

        XYMultipleSeriesRenderer renderer = buildBarRenderer(colors);
        renderer.setOrientation(Orientation.VERTICAL);

        double largeValue = getMax(valueList.get(0)) * 1.1;
        System.out.println(" large " + largeValue);
        int nameSize = 0;
        for (ArrayList<String> nameArray : nameList) {
            int index = 0;
            nameSize = nameArray.size();
            for (String name : nameArray) {
//                if ((index / 2) != 0) {
                renderer.addXTextLabel(index + 1, name);
                index++;
//                }
            }

        }
//        nameSize = 
        int endXValue = (int) (nameSize + 1);
        setChartSettings(renderer, "", "", "", 0,
                endXValue, 0, largeValue, ColorUtil.GREEN, ColorUtil.GREEN);
        renderer.setXLabels(1);
        renderer.setYLabels(8);

        initRendererer(renderer);
        int length = renderer.getSeriesRendererCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            XYSeriesRenderer seriesRenderer = (XYSeriesRenderer) renderer.getSeriesRendererAt(i);
            seriesRenderer.setDisplayChartValues(true);
        }

//        renderer.setYLabelsAlign(Component.LEFT);
        renderer.setXLabelsAlign(Component.RIGHT);

        renderer.setXLabelsAngle(0);
//        renderer.setXAxisMax(10);
        renderer.setShowTickMarks(true);
//        renderer.setBarWidth(50);
//        renderer.setYAxisAlign(Component.CENTER);

        BarChart chart = new BarChart(buildBarDataset2(titles, valueList), renderer,
                Type.DEFAULT) {

                    @Override
                    public void draw(Canvas canvas, int x, int y, int width, int height, Paint paint) {
                        super.draw(canvas, width / 4, y, width, height, paint); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
                    }

                };

        return newChart(chart);
    }
```

This is new image with component Inspector and there is no any spacing
[image: inspector image]

Comment: I noticed you invoke `setPreferredH` on the tabs. Instead place the tabs in the center of a border layout form. I suggest using Component Inspector to review the component sizes and see which one takes up the space and in what way

Comment: I have added new image with inspector and there is no any extra spacing
https://i.stack.imgur.com/wXWP8.png
how can the spacing of the barchart be removed ?

Comment: Try adding the chart to the tabs enclosed within a FlowLayout or BorderLayout

Comment: I have try both above layout  and there is still same problem.

Comment: I suggest isolating the problematic pieces, you have tabs, layouts and a lot of other things. Create an isolated test case with only the chart. If you can't reproduce it the maybe the problem is different, if you can then you have code you can submit to the issue tracker